# Why is my openlayers map disappearing when I add an extent constraint?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, openlayers

I am new to openlayers, and have tried to teach myself what I can through the tutorials.

My map works fine until I add an extent to the view. As soon as I do that, the map disappears. (zoom controls remain).

I have searched the documentation for help with this but no luck.

Here is my code:

```
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
      <script type="text/javascript">

        const extentNESW = [ 4422340.708467, -10578604.167351, 3169996.437043, -9735019.922400 ]
        const extentWSEN = [-9735019.922400, 3169996.437043, -10578604.167351, 4422340.708467 ]
        const centerLonLat = [ -10160621.295892, 3903791.908581 ]

        var map = new ol.Map({

          target: 'map',

          layers: [

            new ol.layer.Tile({
              
              source: new ol.source.OSM()
            
            })
          
          ],

          view: new ol.View({
            
            
            center: (centerLonLat),
            zoom: 10,
            extent: extentWSEN,

            
          })

        });


      </script>
```

If i remove the line with extent, the map works again. What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your extent array has wrong order of coordinates. The order has to be:

> ```
> [minX, minY, maxX, maxY]
> ```

More specifically, in your case, **you have swapped minX and maxX**. Replace your array with the following:

```
const extentWSEN = [-10578604.167351, 3169996.437043, -9735019.922400, 4422340.708467 ];
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked! Can you provide a link to where in the documentation the required order of coordinates is? I looked but couldn't find it and the OL docs are laid out confusingly.

Comment: Here you are: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_extent.html#~Extent (@ Type Definitions)